# Creating or ignoring missing empty directories in Eclipse

Tags: git, eclipse

I recently moved a project from SVN to Git.

Now my Eclipse complains that the directory `src/main/resources` is missing.

The directory was an empty directory in SVN, but Git seems to ignore empty directories entirely.

Can I tell Eclipse to

- either create the directory when checking out the project
- or ignore the "error" completely

?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+empty+directory

Comment: I wonder why Eclipse cares? There’s clearly nothing of interest there. :)

Comment: @phd I read that. I don't want to put fake files into a directory. I want to solve the problem on the Eclipse side.

Comment: Eclipse was designed before git was invented. If you configure a project to have a src/main/resources directory and git doesn't allow empty directories you can not solve it. You can only implement workarounds in git by adding empty files or in Eclipse by modifying the used build script like Maven or Gradle to create the necessary directories that are empty.

Comment: @Robert But aren't many people using Eclipse and Git together for Java development? I cannot believe I am the first person to have this problem.

Comment: See https://github.com/eclipse-m2e/m2e-core/issues/1010 Consider to provide a pull request.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want to put fake files into a directory. I want to solve the problem on the Eclipse side

You can tell Eclipse to ignore certain problems.

- Go to `Window -> Preferences -> Validation`.
- In the Validation page, you can enable or disable individual validators, set the severity of validation messages, and customize other validation behavior.
  Find the validator that's causing the issue and disable it or adjust its settings as necessary.

---

But if there is no matching validator, then... the solution is on Git side.

---

Git provides a mechanism called [`gitattributes`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) that can be used to specify custom actions upon checkout and other events.
The [`filter` attribute](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_filter) allows you to define a pair of "`smudge`" and "`clean`" scripts. The `smudge` script is run on checkout, and the `clean` script is run when files are staged (i.e., added to the index).

In your case, you could create a `smudge` script that creates the directory you need.

- Start with defining a `filter` in your repository's `.git/config` file:

  ```
  [filter "createDir"]
      smudge = 'mkdir -p src/main/resources && cat'
      clean = cat
  ```

  This sets up a filter named "createDir". The smudge command creates the `src/main/resources` directory (if it doesn't exist already) and then passes the file content through `cat` unmodified. The clean command just passes the file content through unchanged.
- Then Apply the filter to a known file of your repository in your `.gitattributes` file (for instance `README.md` if you have one):

  ```
  README.md filter=createDir
  ```

  This applies the "`createDir`" filter to your file `README.md`.

Since it involves the *local* Git config, this process needs to be activated by the developer:

```
git config --local filter.createDir.smudge 'mkdir -p src/main/resources && cat'
git config --local filter.createDir.clean cat

git restore --source=HEAD .
```

Comment: Although this is not what I expected, it sounds like a sensible plan.

Comment: Yes, sadly options are limited on Eclipse side, hence using an official Git feature should be a valid alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can generally hack Git into doing anything you want, and so it is here, but it looks like you're trying to use Git as a deployment server, which it is not (in much the same way as Blender is tantalizingly close to a CAD program, the focus is just wrong enough that moving that direction would hurt its main business).

The hack for getting Git to create an empty directory is to tell it there's supposed to be a separate work tree there.

```
z8=00000000
git update-index --add --cacheinfo 160000,$z8$z8$z8${z8}00000001,path/to/empty/dir
```

and then when you check the committed version of that out Git will make an empty directory there. Have I used the word "hack" enough? The right way to do this is to have a setup script, I have a "setup" target in my makefiles and all the other targets eventually depend on that.

edit: to find all empty directories, `find -empty`.

```
find -type d -name .git -prune -o -type d -empty -exec git update-index etc {} \;
```

or `-exec` whatever you want to do with them.

Comment: Sorry, but I said that I do not want to solve the problem on the git side, but on the Eclipse side. So while your hack might work, this is not what I am looking for. BTW I am not using Git for deployment, just for development.

Comment: It generally helps if you say what you want up front, mentioning Git first in the title and spending a lot of time on how it behaves in the question body before remarking that you'd like to fix Eclipse led me to believe otherwise. I fixed your title and tags.

Comment: Sorry to confuse you, thanks for your efforts. The problem lies in the "communication" between Eclipse and Git, but it would be much better to fix it on the Eclipse side.